# changing the background color of each cell in the form in extjs

Tags: extjs4

In grid for changing the background color of a cell we have code something like this:

```
   .later .x-grid-cell {
         background-color: #FFB0C4 !important;     
   } 
   .now .x-grid-cell {
         background-color: #5491BD !important;     
   }
```

Is there anything like this for changing the background color of each cell in the form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the property is

```
.value .x-form-field{
    background : red;
}
```

This must change the background of each field if you change the cls to value.

If you want to change separately each field you must add the fieldStyle property

```
fieldStyle: 'background: blue;'
```

In this fiddle there is an example 
http://jsfiddle.net/lisssb/Ln6PT/4/

I hope this help

Comment: But it gives color only to the fields like textbox, combobox, etc. It does not give color to the labels as well as the space remains after the textbox, combo box, etc.

Comment: I dont know if I understand you well, 
but here ther is a modification of the fiddle, it is something like this what you want?
http://jsfiddle.net/lisssb/Ln6PT/6/

Comment: I already tried it. But in that they are giving `anchor: '98%'`. But I don't want to give it. If I remove it, the spaces after the textbox remains blank with white color. I want it to be filled with the same color.

Comment: This is my last try.. xD

add display : block to the property.
http://jsfiddle.net/lisssb/Ln6PT/8/

Comment: Ya this is I want. Thank you so much. It works fine in ExtJS 4.2.0. But I want it to work in ExtJS 4.1.0.

Comment: I think that the property to change instead of x.table-plain is .x-form-item
http://jsfiddle.net/lisssb/Ln6PT/9/

Comment: Thank you. But in that they are referring class in the form scope `cls: 'value'`. But I want it to be referred for item and not for full form because I am setting this color only for few cells in the form not for all the cells.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/lisssb/Ln6PT/11/

in the lines 18 and 19 you can see the modifications, style and fieldStyle.

you can customize for each field.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is what I wanted. I was trying for the past 1 month. But I didn't get it. Thank you very much once again.

Comment: This is working fine in Mozilla Firefox. But it is not working in IE and chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the fieldStyle:

```
fieldStyle: 'background-color: #ddd; background-image: none;'
```

Comment: I already tried but it is giving color for only the fields like textbox. I want to give color to label as well as the spaces after the textbox.